# How to have customers upload a image directly to my ubuntu16 server?

Tags: php, image, input, upload, ubuntu-16.04

i have a html form for uploading images. i have a additional php file for the action. but the upload itself keeps failing what did i do wrong?

here is the html form  and the php

HTML FORM :

```
<form class="row" id="uploadbanner" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="./upload.php">
<input id="fileupload" name="myfile" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

PHP (upload.php)

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <?php

 $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

 $location = "./uploads/".$filename;

 if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location)){
echo 'erfolgreich gesendet!';
 }else{
echo 'Problem beim Senden!';
 }
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

i have als made a directory named : uploads. and its in the same folder as the upload.php

i gave 755 permission to the folder with command: chmod 755 /var/www/html/uploads -R

what did i do wrong?

Comment: failing how, precisely? You didn't tell us what indications you are getting.

Comment: i get the echo: problem with sending. so the form does submit but te image never uploads to the directory

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php says _If from is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return false._ You haven't reported getting a warning, so this is the most likely explanation for the issue. Your code does not check if the file is valid before proceeding to try and move it. Read about the "error" property in $_FILES, to begin with - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php. Maybe one of those errors is happening.

Comment: Or, it might just be a simple typo, as the answer below has now noted. Some basic debugging (e.g. using `var_dump($_FILES);`) might have highlighted that to you. Did you do any simple tests?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input's name is "myfile", instead of the "file" name that you're currently looking at. Correcting that should make the script work as you're expecting

```php
<?php
$tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];

$location = "./uploads/" . $filename;

if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location)) {
    echo 'erfolgreich gesendet!';
} else {
    echo 'Problem beim Senden!';
}
```

Comment: Normally we just vote to close when it's a simple typo

Comment: I wouldn't count this as much of a typo (since the type of "file" _could_ what had been clued on); a misspelled function name would be more of a typo in my book, at least

Comment: It's a simple mismatch between the name on the form field and the name used in the PHP to read from that field. It might not be a slip of the fingers on the keys exactly, but it's a trivial mistake which is of no real interest to anyone else.

Comment: @ChrisForrence it still does not work . still get the problem while sending echo. additional note: al the files are in the /var/www/html location. maybe i need to do something else to make it work?